# setting up Jetty 8.1.16 with pre-installed/configured Oskari in my ubuntu 15.04

Tags: java, jetty-8

I am setting up Jetty 8.1.16 with pre-installed/configured Oskari in my ubuntu 15.04 by following [this tutorial](http://www.oskari.org/documentation/backend/setup-jetty). After starting up the jetty and points to http://localhost:8080 it is taking me to default tomcat7 home page. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have tomcat running? Either kill tomcat or change port of jetty(`-Djetty.port=8081`),

Comment: Yes thanks. This works.